# Excel - How to add cells that have letters and numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

For example:

A1 - "AA123"

How do I get B1 to read "AA124" and C1 to read "AA125"?

I know that in A1 I can drag the box to the right and it will populate with this, but I need a formula for this.  I will be placing the formula into a independent barcode generating program that does not have the drag feature.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You mean grabbing a data from a cell to another ?

Example : let's say that cell A1 = (ABCD) and you want to grab cell A1 data into cell D15.
to do that you can type on cell D15 this formula `=A1` this will grab what cell A1 has and show it in cell D15.

if you want to use formula combination in cells, you just type directly `=` into the cell, and then type your formula then hit **Enter**.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about incrementing the numeric part of the first cell.

Comment: Oh, my bad, you can use this formula `="AA " & COLUMN(A1) + 119` This will make `A1= AA 120`if you copy it to B1, it'll be AA 121, and so on! I hope this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & --MID(A1,3,9999)+1
```

and copy across.

Answer (score 0):

If A1 = AA123

Then A2 can be:

`="AA" & MID(A1,3,3)+1`

That will give AA124

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume your data is always text, then digits, but you don't want to
make assumptions about what the text contains, you can extract the two
components, increment the numeric part, and reassemble them.

To find the first digit, use this [magic incantation](http://forums.excelcentral.com/index.php?/topic/491-separating-text-and-numbers-in-excel/) which searches for *all* the digits
and then takes the min of the offsets:

```
=MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, B1 & "0123456789"))
```

The extra string appended to B1 ensures that FIND will succeed for every 
search, so it doesn't throw #VALUE!.

Then it's just a matter us using LEFT, RIGHT, and LEN to pull out the pieces 
and put them back together.

[image: step-by-step extraction and reassembly]

Note that the long formula can be hidden in a "named formula" (like a named range) if necessary.